# Duda con Kotlin CRUD SugarROM

Tags: android-studio, lista, kotlin, crud, sugarcrm

Cuándo le doy click al botón de listar, no pasa nada. Ya cambié por SugarRecord.listAll (ya
qué en kotlin tengo entendido que la clase secundaria no hereda el método estático del padre
por que la estática no existe en Kotlin). También, realicé la devida implementación en el
gradle:     implementation("com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5"). Voy a mostrar solamente lo más
relevante del código:

```
import com.orm.SugarContext
import com.orm.SugarRecord


    SugarContext.init(this)

    buttonList.setOnClickListener {
        listPets()
    }
}

fun listPets() {
    Log.d("PetList", "Entrando en listPets()")
    val pets = SugarRecord.listAll(Pet::class.java)
    if (pets.isNotEmpty()) {
        for (pet in pets) {
            println("Nombre: ${pet.name}, Edad: ${pet.age}, Tipo: ${pet.type}")
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay mascotas registradas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

}